# XLSX file: Unable to write to the same workbook

Tags: java, static, apache-poi, xlsx

I have written a code to pick data for certain area in the input excel and the transpose and paste it in the output excel. This read and write are 2 separate methods, which i call from main method. However, once the code runs and the file is generated, it only shows the data written for the last write method call. As per my understanding, it has to be because, my code is creating a new workbook object every time. Though i have tried to overcome this by using static keyword in my code. Please see below for the code.

```
public class DataExtractor {

    static FileOutputStream output = null;
    static XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    static XSSFSheet sheet = null;
    static XSSFWorkbook outputWorkbook = null;
    static XSSFSheet outputSheet = null;
    static XSSFRow row = null;
    DataFormatter dataFormatter = null;
    public DataExtractor(XSSFWorkbook workbook, XSSFSheet sheet, XSSFWorkbook outputWorkbook, XSSFSheet outputSheet) {
        DataExtractor.workbook = workbook;
        DataExtractor.sheet = sheet;
        DataExtractor.outputWorkbook = outputWorkbook;
        DataExtractor.outputSheet = outputSheet;
        }

        private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fetchDataFromInputExcel(){

            //code for fetching data from excel/reading excel only for some grids.

        }

        private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> pasteTransposedDataIntoOutputExcel(){

            //code for transposing data and pasting it into output excel/writing to excel.

        }

        public static void main(String args[]){
                File file = new File("path of xlsx file");
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
                sheet = workbook.getSheet("SHEETNAME");
                outputWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                outputSheet = outputWorkbook.createSheet("OUTPUT");
                DataExtractor obj = new DataExtractor(workbook, sheet, outputWorkbook, outputSheet);
                ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> header = dataExtractor.fetchDataFromInputExcel(//args for mentioning grid area row and col are passed here);
                ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = dataExtractor.fetchDataFromInputExcel(//args for mentioning grid area row and col are passed here);

                dataExtractor.pasteTransposedDataIntoOutputExcel(dataExtractor, data, 1, 8);
                dataExtractor.pasteTransposedDataIntoOutputExcel(dataExtractor, header, 1, 1);

                output = new FileOutputStream(new File("path of output.xlsx file"));
                outputWorkbook.write(output);
        }

}
```

Only `dataExtractor.pasteTransposedDataIntoOutputExcel(dataExtractor, header, 1, 1`) operation is performed and i do not see the data for the previous one. Please suggest.

Method for transposeAndPaste:

```
private boolean transposeAndPasteData(DataExtractor dataExtractor, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data, int startRowNum, int startColNum){
        XSSFCell cell = null;
        XSSFRow row = null;
        outputWorkbook = dataExtractor.getOutputWorkbook();
        outputSheet = dataExtractor.getOutputSheet();
        try {
            int startRowIndex = startRowNum - 1;
            int startColIndex = startColNum - 1;
            //paste data row wise
            //for(int rowNum = startColNum-1; rowNum<startColNum+data.size(); rowNum++) {}

            Iterator<ArrayList<String>> colItr = data.iterator();
            while(colItr.hasNext()) {
                row = outputSheet.createRow(startRowIndex++);
                ArrayList<String> colData = colItr.next();
                Iterator<String> rowItr = colData.iterator();

                while(rowItr.hasNext()) {
                    cell = row.createCell(startColIndex++);
                    cell.setCellValue(rowItr.next());
                }
                startColIndex = startColNum - 1;
            }

            dataExtractor.setOutputSheet(outputSheet);
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
```

Thanks,
Aman

Comment: The problem must be in code of method `pasteTransposedDataIntoOutputExcel` which we don't know.

Comment: @AxelRichter added the code for the same.

Comment: In `row = outputSheet.createRow(startRowIndex++);` `outputSheet.createRow(startRowIndex++)` always creates a new empty row. So formerly values in that row get deleted. Do replacing that with `row = outputSheet.getRow(startRowIndex); if (row==null) row = outputSheet.createRow(startRowIndex); startRowIndex++;`. Not sure this is the one and only problem, that's why not posted as answer. But for sure it is one problem.

Comment: @axel Richter this was the only issue indeed. It was creating a new row object everytime. Thanks for your prompt help.